# C++ Manager that holds instances of objects

Tags: c++, oop

In my current project I plan to use multiple instances of what I'll call `Profile`.
A `Profile` consists of a bunch of methods and information, like so

```
class Profile
{
public:
    std::string name() const;
    int id() const;

    void setName(const std::string& name);
};
```

The idea is that `Profile` will contain more information as the project evolves.

Now, instinctively I want to use a `ProfileManager` to keep track of, load, create and delete `Profile` instances. But in that case, the `Profile` must have an instance or a pointer to an instance of the `ProfileManager`, because It'll need to check if any other profile already has the name provided in the `setName(const std::string& name)` method, as such:

```
void Profile::setName(const std::string& name) {
    for(Profile* profile : manager->profiles()) {
        if(profile->name() == name) {
            //Ooops, a profile with that name already exists
        }
}
```

**1. Is it a bad idea to keep a manager in the managed object?**

My idea is also that each `Profile` lives in it's own directory, like `profiles/john/profile.xml` where `john` could be any arbitrary directory name.

The `ProfileManager` would then scan each directory in search of a `profile.xml` file, and parse that file to extract information about the `Profile`, and create a new one out of it.

That would mean that the `ProfileManager` needs a `void load(const std::string& rootDir)` function. But in order to set the different variables based on the information in the XML file, the `ProfileManager` and `Profile` needs to be friends.

Another solution would be to have a `static Profile* Profile::parse(const std::string& xmlFile)` function in the `Profile`. But then again, the `Profile` will utlimately need a reference to the `ProfileManager`. So maybe that isn't a very nice solution.

**2. Should I separate the functions into different classes? (ProfileFactory, ProfileManager etc.)?**

I also need to be able to create `Profile`s during runtime.

What would be a clean, not-so-error-prone structure/solution to all this?

Comment: Why not keep a **static** `std::vector` of the names?

Comment: Why does a profile need to know whether another profile already has the same name?!? Wouldn't it be the *manager*'s responsibility to make sure there are no duplicate profiles?

Comment: Kerrek SB is right, you're talking about creating a circular reference between Profiles and ProfileManagers.  Here's a good discussion as to why that's a poor design: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references

Comment: Possibly the `ProfileManager` could be an embellishment of a `std::map` or `std::set` with the key being the name of the `Profile`?

Comment: If there is only one `ProfileManager`, it can be global object or [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Or, you can make the `Profile`'s constructors private, add `ProfileManager` to `Profile`'s friends. Then, if you need to create single `Profile`'s object, you would have to do it by calling `ProfileManager`'s method...

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, it seems logical that it's up to the manager, but then how should I in a clean manner change the name of a Profile? manager.setName(profile, newName)?

Comment: @Josh Yeah, that's an idea I haven't pondered, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @xarxer: Think about it more systematically. Where do your profiles come from? Why would someone send you a profile? Do those people have a way of figuring out in advance whether they'll be allowed to use a certain name? Can they ask you to assign a new, unique name? Etc etc.

Comment: Well then, to be more precise, what would be a good way to manage Profiles in any manner? I'm especially curious about the setName() problem.